# Rewrite SQL Query for Use With Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

```php
$query = "SELECT *, (id.number_of_candidates - t.counted) as available 
    FROM interview_dates id 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT interview_dates_id,COUNT(interview_dates_id) as counted 
        FROM date_timeslot GROUP BY interview_dates_id) as t 
    ON t.interview_dates_id=id.id 
    WHERE id.number_of_candidates > t.counted";
```

Please help me to rewrite this using Laravel Query Builder.